# Cannot upload program to Arduino Duemilanove w/ Atmega328

Tags: arduino-due, uploading, atmega328, ftdi

[image: Upload Debug]

This is the error I receive while trying to upload to the Arduino.
I have installed FTDI drivers for mac. (http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP/MacOSX/FTDIUSBSerialDriver_v2_2_18.dmg)

The board is part of a quadcopter: https://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/uh_viewItem.asp?idProduct=50460

The processor is an Atmel 328P. Do I have the correct drivers?

What else could be the issue?

Comment: You shouldn't need to load any drivers for your Mac; it should (mine does) recognize your FTDI USB device the moment you plug it in.

Answer (score 1):

You may have wrong port:  **/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007LXq** works with Duemilanove on my Mac.

Comment: You can check this by opening a terminal and typing in ls/dev/tty. and then hitting tab. It should tell you all the open ports